# Создание анимации с простейшими геометрическими фигурами

Tags: c++, qt, анимация, qpropertyanimation, qgraphicsitem

Хочу создать геометрическую фигуру (к примеру, квадрат), чтобы она мигала. Понимаю, что надо использовать класс `QPropertyAnimation`.

В конструкторе этого класса такое определение `QPropertyAnimation ( QObject * target, const QByteArray & propertyName, QObject * parent = 0 )`.

Мною был создан класс с отрисовкой геометрической фигуры, который наследуется от `QGraphicsItem`.

```
class Rect: public QGraphicsItem {
private:
    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
public:
    Rect();
    ~Rect();
protected:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);    
};
```

Но при создании объекта класса `QPropertyanimation` он не принимает в качестве аргумента мой объект. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `QPropertyAnimation` в качестве объекта анимации принимается указатель на `QObject`, следовательно, от этого класса вам надо наследовать ваш `Rect` (лучше выбрать другое имя). Это первое. Второе, мигание подразумевает изменение цвета, а для того, чтобы `QPropertyAnimation` "добрался" до соответствующего свойства объекта, его (свойство) необходимо определить через макрос `Q_PROPERTY`:

```
class Rect: public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor flashingColor READ flashingColor WRITE setFlashingColor)

public:
    void setFlashingColor(const QColor& color) {
        flashingColor = color;
        update();
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
       // рисуем фигуру цветом flashingColor
    }
```

Анимация задается вот так (если указатель на объект `QPropertyAnimation` создается в конструкторе класса `Rect`):

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this , "flashingColor");
animation->setDuration(1000);
animation->setStartValue(QColor(0, 0, 0));
animation->setEndValue(QColor(255, 255, 255));
animation->start();
```

Comment: Благодарю за такой подробный и развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: скажите: а почему в аргумент я не могу, собственно, поставить свой объект, унаследованный от QGraphicsItem? Ведь последний является наследником QObject насколько я понимаю. Возможно, я путаю принципы наследования: т.е, дочерний класс родителя не может "встать" вместо своего предка. Но вроде по принципу ООП это вполне возможно

Comment: @Bizzarro QGraphicsItem это базовый класс целой серии классов для работы с QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsView, он ни от кого не наследуется. См. док

Comment: а если мне необходимо сделать, грубо говоря, два мигания одним цветом и остановить анимацию- как этого можно достичь? Именно мигание (резкая смена цвета, без постепенного изменения цвета?

Comment: @Bizzarro можно и через анимацию, можно и таймером